# JqueryUI datepicker overwriting existing date value with current date - KnockoutJS

Tags: jquery-ui, knockout.js

I have a form in a jqueryUI dialog box with a list of dates populated from a KnockoutJS observableArray.

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: $root.selectedListOfDates">
<tr><td><input type="text" data-bind="datepicker: DueDate" /></td></tr>
</tbody
```

My issue is that when I load a new object with a list of dates, the original values of the dates in the input box are overwritten by the current date (I presume when the Jquery datepicker is loaded).

Here is my datepicker binding:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.datepicker = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
        var options = allBindingsAccessor().datepickerOptions || {},
            $el = $(element);

        //initialize datepicker with some optional options
        $el.datepicker(options);

        //handle the field changing
        ko.utils.registerEventHandler(element, "change", function() {
            var observable = valueAccessor();
            observable($el.datepicker("getDate"));
        });

        //handle disposal (if KO removes by the template binding)
        ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(element, function() {
            $el.datepicker("destroy");
        });

    },
    update: function(element, valueAccessor) {
        var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor()),
            $el = $(element),
            current = $el.datepicker("getDate");

        if (value - current !== 0) {
            $el.datepicker("setDate", value);   
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Does your options variable in init include gotoCurrent: true?  I believe the jQuery datepicker will otherwise use new Date() by default.

```
var options = options || {};
options.goToCurrent = true;
$el.datepicker(options);
```

http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Comment: I threw it in there but still same result.

Comment: You're not initializing the datepicker in init. $el.datapicker(options); $el.datepicker("setDate", valueAccessor());

Comment: It did not like it. Uncaught TypeError: Unable to process binding "datepicker: function (){return DueDate }"
Message: i.getTime is not a function

Comment: Is DueDate a javascript Date object or a string?

Comment: I'm a bit over my head so pardon my explanation. I used the Knockout mapper to map an array of objects sent over from the ASP MVC controller. It appears to be a JS date: "/Date(1462507200000)/"